# vector approach to the descendants of abstract classes

Tags: c++

I would first like to apologize for my English is not very good. I have a problem and do not know what to do with it. I am using a vector in which retain pointers to objects abstract class wagon. Descendants of this class have their own defined function to extract information about the wagons. I do not know if I solved correctly, but when I go through the cycle once the element at the specified index  disappears of me and Vector Here the remains only _vfptr so if I want to again ride the cycle now I'm not list anything. I'll be glad for any advice how do you handle you, or me, you can even ask for something. function Vypis() in my parent class is pure virtual and that I can not call.

```
for (int i = 0; i < _vagony.size(); i++){
        cout << " - ";

        if (typeid(*_vagony.at(i)) == typeid(DinningCar))
            {
                dinCar= dynamic_cast<DinningCar*>(_vagony.at(i));
                dinCar->Vypis();
            }
        if (typeid(*_vagony.at(i)) == typeid(BedWagon))
            {
                bedWag= dynamic_cast<BedWagon*>(_vagony.at(i));
                bedWag->Vypis();
            }
            if (typeid(*_vagony.at(i)) == typeid(PassangerWagon))
            {
                passWag= dynamic_cast<PassangerWagon*>(_vagony.at(i));
                passWag->Vypis();
            }
    }
```

Comment: You're doing it wrong! Make the `Vypis` function `virtual` and the correct method in the child-class will be called automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can dispatch the correct method via virtual functions. Take the following example:

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class Wagon {
 public:
  virtual ~Wagon() = default;
  virtual void Vypis() const {
    std::cout << "Wagon" << std::endl;
  }
};

class DinningCar
    : public Wagon {
  void Vypis() const {
    std::cout << "DinningCar" << std::endl;
  }
};

class BedWagon
    : public Wagon {
  void Vypis() const {
    std::cout << "BedWagon" << std::endl;
  }
};

class PassengerWagon
    : public Wagon {
  void Vypis() const {
    // suppose you also want this particular wagon to call the
    // "generic" method (that is, the one implemented by the parent
    // class)
    Wagon::Vypis();
    std::cout << "PassengerWagon" << std::endl;
  }
};

int main() {

  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Wagon>> wagons;

  wagons.emplace_back(new DinningCar);
  wagons.emplace_back(new BedWagon);
  wagons.emplace_back(new PassengerWagon);
  wagons.emplace_back(new DinningCar);
  wagons.emplace_back(new Wagon);

  for(const auto& wagon : wagons) {
    wagon->Vypis();
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Compile:

```
g++ Wagons.cpp -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra
```

and run:

```
$ ./a.out
DinningCar
BedWagon
Wagon
PassengerWagon
DinningCar
Wagon
```

Notice how you can choose whether to call the parent's implementation (as in `PassengerWagon`) or just the children implementation; C++ will handle internally the virtual function dispatch.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry I forgot to write that in parrent class I have pure virtual function.
Thanks for your answer, at first I did it simply: _vagony.at (i) ->Vypis(); but it did not work dropped me because the function Vypis() in my parent class is pure virtual and that I can not call. –